# BERT:Question-Answering - Total number of permissible words/tokens for training

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, language-model, bert-language-model

Let's say I want to train BERT with 2 sentences (query-answer) pair against a certain binary label (1,0) for the correctness of the answer,  will BERT let me use 512 words/tokens each for the query and the answer or together(query+answer combined) they should be 512? [510 upon ignoring the [start] and [sep] token]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together, and actually it's together they should be 509 since there are two [SEP], one after question and another after answer:

```
[CLS] q_word1 q_word2 ... [SEP] a_word1 a_word2 ... [SEP]
```

where `q_word` refers to words in the question and `a_word` refers to words in the answer

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the information. But since my answers are super long (approx 500 words each), can you help me suggest a few ways around to get over this?

Comment: so first thing to try, of course, is to simply throw away the overlong part (since it's just a small portion, most of time should not affect a lot on the results). if the answers are really too long (e.g. > 1000 etc) maybe u can try split them into half and train seperately

Comment: All the white spaces are also considered to be individual tokens in the BERT tokenizer or only the words are considered to be tokens here? @Crystina

Comment: actually neither, words need to be further tokenized by the WordPiece tokenizer, (which huggingface provides), and the final tokens are usually the sub-words

Comment: I see. So given a sentence of let's say 500 words, I really don't have control over the length of the tokens i.e. chances are all the 500 words might not fit into the max_seq_length after the sentence being divided into subwords? I use the hugging face interface and can I have control over which words are being truncated by chance or which tokens are being tokenized?